# Angular 2: ngFor with dynamic templates/components

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm hoping someone familiar with ng2's inner workings, particular around dynamic component loader and view containers, will be able to help me with an unusual problem. We're trying to create a directive with some of the same change detection semantics of ngFor (that is, you bind it to a collection and it reacts when the collection changes, adding/removing child elements/components) but rather than simply repeating a template X number of times, we need to be able to dynamically load (and configure) individual components. For instance if PageComponent is defined as follows:

```
export interface PageComponent {
    /**
     * The name of the component. Must be unique.
     */
    name: string;
    /**
     * The category to which the component belongs
     */
    category: ComponentCategory;
    /**
     * The conditions under which the component should be displayed/hidden
     */
    displayConditions?: Array<DisplayCondition>;
    /**
     * The list of inputs for the component.
     * It as a map of the input name (unique per component) to the associated 
     * input metadata
     */
    inputs?: {[key: string]: InputMetadata};
    /**
     * The child components, if any, that comprise this @link(PageComponent)
     */
    components?: Array<PageComponent>;
}
```

We'd need the directive to take an array of PageComponents and render the resulting component(s) (assume that a lookup service exists to map from component name to component type). Looking at the implementation of ngFor in ng2's source it does alot of what we need except that it relies on providing a template (it creates an EmbededView) where as we'd probably need to use DCL to create a HostView. 
Does anyone have any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Not sure what the question is about. I think DCL does what you need. What part exactly doesn't yet work as expected?

Comment: It's not about things not working as expected. I'm looking for advice on how to accomplish the scenario described above: an ngFor like directive (change detection on a collection so it can add/remove components as needed) that, instead of repeating a given template X times, places components defined by the PageComponent interface above (which as you can see, can be a tree).